# MAUI Button text not adjusted to the size of the button

Tags: xamarin, maui

Having the Following Content page

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PhotobookUI.TableContentPage"
             Title="TableContentPage">

    <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill">
        <HorizontalStackLayout

                HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                HeightRequest="20"
                VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Button
                x:Name="BackButton"
                Text="Back"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Back"
                Clicked="OnBackClicked"
                CornerRadius="0"
                VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The button looks like this:
[image]

I tried lots of `VerticalOptions`, `MaximumHeight` request, nothing seems to work.

How can I make the button to adjust its height and the text to be in the center of the button which seems to be overlaid by the horizontal stack layout?

P.S. I'm trying to shrink the button to 20, not to display it's default height.

Answer (score 1):

- Maui does not have auto-sizing fonts. It will not automatically shrink FontSize to fit text in a smaller area, either horizontally or vertically.
- Specify a smaller font size in Button's properties.
- If that change doesn't automatically shrink button height, then set Button's HeightRequest.
- Probably don't need to set a HeightRequest on HorizontalStackLayout: it should automatically size to fit its contents.

Code:

```xml
    <Button FontSize="10" HeightRequest="20" ... />
```

Comment: The font is indeed shrinking when setting FontSize, but HeightRequest has no effect.

Comment: Hmm. There must be internal padding around the text, on the button. I don't have time to look into it. Maui Button source files are in folder https://github.com/dotnet/maui/tree/main/src/Controls/src/Core/Button. Might be able to subclass Button; define your own `MyButton : Button`. If not, would need custom handler per platform. Search for previous StackOverflow posts for examples.

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not need to add the `HorizontalStackLayout` on the `VerticalStackLayout`.

Second, if you set the height 20 for the `HorizontalStackLayout` it will not let the button show correctly.

Here is the code I changed and it works well.

```
 <VerticalStackLayout >  
                <Button
                    x:Name="BackButton"
                    Text="Back"
                    SemanticProperties.Hint="Back"
                    Clicked="BackButton_Clicked"
                    CornerRadius="0"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
           
        </VerticalStackLayout>
```

Comment: The point is to constrain the button to be smaller(20) in height, sorry if I was not clear in the question, I edited it.

Comment: You can add the `HeightRequest ="20"` to the Button and remove the `HorizontalStackLayout`.